# Numpy error on .arange command

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use sklearn nmf on a binary file (.bin) imported via numpy and converted to uint8. I import the file no problem, but it's coming in as a 1D array, and when I try and arrange into a 2D array (which sklearn.NMF requires) it errors. I have imported numpy and sklearn.

Import data:

```
m1 = np.fromfile('file', dtype='uint8')
```

Code it errors on (I added the - symbol following advice from the docs, it also errors without the - symbol):

```
m1.arange(962240400).reshape((31020,-31020))
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'arange'
```

I have tried looking at the official docs and stack overflow, but nothing seems to be working. If anyone has any ideas as to why my code is wrong that would be great.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.arange(962240400).reshape((31020,-31020))`, it is a function of numpy, not a method of the array `m1`

Comment: Thanks Joe, that stopped the error, I knew I must be missing something - (sound of head thumping repeatedly on desk) - and looking at the docs once the new shape is created I then fill with the data.

Comment: @desertnaut, thanks for the steer, have accepted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

use arange in place of arrange.there should only one 'r'

Comment: It's possible Julian has quoted his Python program incorrectly, but in his question "arrange" does not occur in the actual Python quote. Are you sure this is the problem?